# Is it legal for the compiler to assume that a static variable will not be modified by another thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I'm a bit surprised that the compiler (gcc) is simply assuming that a static variable will never be touched by other threads even with the lowest optimization level. I was trying to read a value written from another thread, but gcc simply thinks the value has never changed. Is reading a value of a static variable modified by another thread undefined behaviour per the standard?

I'm specifically asking about the assumption the compiler is making. Not about what happens when a program is not correctly handling thread synchronization.

---

To clarify for future readers, only the selected answer clearly answers my question as written in the title. It didn't solve the actual problem I had, but that was what I asked. Still, I'd like to clarify what the actual problem was, and how I finally understood what the compiler was doing.

Given a static global variable `n`,

```
static int n;
```

I put `n` in a loop to make a faulty spin lock.

```
while (!n); doSth();
```

Unless `n` is `volatile` or `_Atomic`, the compiler will simply assume that the value of `n` will not change inside the loop.

Then I noticed that the part of code relying on a signal handler was working as expected.

```
n = 0; //added for explanation
sigset_t s;
sigemptyset(&s);
sigaddset(&s, SIGUSR1);
sigwait(&s, (int *)&_);
if (n) doSth(); //the compiler still checks the value of `n`
```

I first thought something special is going on with `sigwait`, but that was not true. With this simpler example,

```
n = 0;
putchar(0);
if (n) doSth();
```

the compiler still cannot assume the value of `n` is `0` because `putchar` might have a side effect modifying the value of `n` since `n` is a global variable.

Of course, any sane compiler will optimize out this.

```
n = 0;
if (n) doSth();
```

After all, everything is working fine with a nice signal handler.

Comment: @sj95216 That only applies to data race conditions when "neither happens before the other". What if the value is read clearly after a modification from another thread?

Comment: In general, if the variable is not `volatile`, atomic, or protected from access by memory barriers, the optimizer will optimize access to it as if it's single threaded.

Comment: in most cases it's not even asumption of compiler but of cpu itself because values in memory are cached  through multi-level cache buffer. Compiler's concern is only about volatile, which cannot be used as replacement to atomic operations, etc.

Comment: I don't think the rules for static variables (re: multithreading) are any different than the rules for variables in general.

Comment: @xiver77 Can you explain precisely what you mean by "clearly after"? I would argue that to show that B happens "clearly after" A, you must show that a program that strictly complies with the standard can have different observable behavior depending on which happens first. That can be much harder than you think because of the "as-if" rule. For example, `a=2; printf("hello\n"); b=3;` The assignment to `b` is not "clearly after" `a` because no standard-compliant program can tell which happened first (assuming `a` and `b` are ordinary integers).

Comment: @xiver77 "happens before" does not have the colloquial meaning. It is a technical term defined in 5.1.2.4.18. In particular "happens before" means either sequenced before in the same thread or synchronized in some way through an atomic/mutex/fence.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: "thread B is waiting"/"thread A sends a signal": The question is how this is implemented. If it is done correctly, then the signal will be synchronizing the write and read to the static, so that the compiler cannot make any assumption on its state after the signal is received. But if it is improperly implemented (e.g. just reading/writing a non-atomic global), then the compiler doesn't need to consider changes by other threads.

Comment: @xiver77 it you're using asynchronous signals, you need `volatile` for every non-local variable modified in the signal handler, in order for it to become visible in the normal part of the thread. If you're handling signals synchronously using `sigwaitinfo` or `signalfd` (or emulating `signalfd` (poorly, beware a full pipe!) using the self-pipe trick) the syscall provides ordering guarantees for you.

Comment: @o11c Is that advise specific about some particular platform? If so, which? If you think it's platform-independent, can you explain what standard requires that every platform have this behavior?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The advice is for all platforms, though some particular approaches are platform-dependent. `signal` is specified by C (but `sigaction` is preferred if you have POSIX). `pipe` is POSIX, but equivalents exist on non-POSIX platforms. `sigwait`/`sigwaitinfo`/`sigtimedwait` are POSIX. `signalfd` is Linux-specific. I don't think any other functions are relevant - particularly, `kqueue` on the BSDs does not return enough info to be sure that the signal came from who you think it did.

Comment: @o11c Just to start, you don't *need* `volatile` on any platform that I know of. Every platform I've seen has thread-visibility mechanisms other than `volatile` that serve this purpose. And I've yet to see a platform-independent guarantee around `volatile` when applied to anything but `sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Doing it without `volatile` absolutely will break things; the only working alternative to get data out of a signal handler is to use `_Atomic` instead (remember: without this you can't *know* that you got the signal asynchronously). Regarding `sigatomic_t`: I can't see any way to construct a platform that supports `volatile` but does not allow other types in a signal handler - I'm aware of old 36-bit platforms that implemented bytes via masking, but those cannot support `volatile char` at *all*.

Comment: @o11c If using `_Atomic` instead works, the `volatile` isn't necessary. That not using `volatile` breaks things only proves that it's not guaranteed to work without `volatile`. It doesn't show that it's guaranteed to work with `volatile`. And arguments based on what you can and can't see don't produce *guarantees*. You can't say something will work just because you can't think of a platform on which it wouldn't work. You cannot imagine how much pain that kind of reasoning has caused over the years.

Comment: Instead of posting the solution to your problem in the question itself, it would seem more appropriate to me to post an answer to your own question. See this official help page for more information: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I just made the edit because a lot of people seemed to be confused on what I was asking about, so I also showed the actual problem and the solution I got, to clarify. The only reason why I didn't accept your answer is because I disagreed with your interpretation of the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOR THOSE WHO DO NOT READ AND DV. THIS ANSWER IS NOT RELATED THE IPC only answers the first question asked. IPC is too broad and complicated for a short SO answer. I do not write about race conditions, atomicity or coherency.

> I'm a bit surprised that the compiler (gcc) is simply assuming that a
> static variable will never be touched by other threads even with the
> lowest optimization level.
>
> 5.1.2.4.4 in the standard reads "Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or
> modifies the same memory location."

You ask two distinct questions. The first one is about side effects. The second about IPC mechanisms.

I will answer only the first one as the second is too broad to be answered here on SO.

The compiler is assuming that objects (variables) can be changed only if the code changing them is in the normal program execution path.

If not, it assumes that those objects will not be changed.

But **C**  has a special keyword `volatile`. It informs the compiler that **`volatile`** object is side effects prone - ie it can be changed by something outside the normal program execution path. The compiler will generate read form the object storage location every time it is used, and write the object storage location on every modification.

Example:

```
unsigned counter1;
volatile unsigned counter2;

int interruptHandler1(void)
{
    counter1++;
}

void foo(void)
{
    while(1)
        if(counter1 > 100) printf("Larger!!!!");
}

int interruptHandler2(void)
{
    counter2++;
}

void bar(void)
{
    while(1)
        if(counter2 > 100) printf("Larger!!!!");
}
```

Output code:

```
interruptHandler1:
        add     DWORD PTR counter1[rip], 1
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "Larger!!!!"
foo:
        cmp     DWORD PTR counter1[rip], 100
        ja      .L12
.L11:
        jmp     .L11
.L12:
        push    rax
.L4:
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        cmp     DWORD PTR counter1[rip], 100
        ja      .L4
.L8:
        jmp     .L8
interruptHandler2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR counter2[rip], eax
        ret
bar:
.L20:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        cmp     eax, 100
        jbe     .L20
        sub     rsp, 8
.L19:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
.L15:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        cmp     eax, 100
        jbe     .L15
        jmp     .L19
counter2:
        .zero   4
counter1:
        .zero   4
```

`volatile` object will be read at *any* access from the permanent storage location:

```
int foo1(void)
{
    return counter1 + counter1 + counter1 + counter1;
}

int bar1(void)
{
    return counter2 + counter2 + counter2 + counter2;
}
```

```
foo1:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR counter1[rip]
        sal     eax, 2
        ret
bar1:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        add     eax, esi
        add     eax, ecx
        add     eax, edx
        ret
```

And saved on  every modification:

```
void foo2(void)
{
    counter1++;
    counter1++;
    counter1++;
    counter1++;
}

void bar2(void)
{
    counter2++;
    counter2++;
    counter2++;
    counter2++;
}
```

```
foo2:
        add     DWORD PTR counter1[rip], 4
        ret
bar2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR counter2[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR counter2[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR counter2[rip], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR counter2[rip]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR counter2[rip], eax
        ret
```

Comment: Even with the `volatile`, the program has a data race and thus undefined behavior.

Comment: Alternative to volatile for when using synchronization primitives: pass the address of the variable to a do-nothing function _in a different translation unit_. With modern toolchains a different `.c` file won't be good enough. My be-absolutely-sure method would be to write the three lines of assembly but putting it in a different shared library would also work. (Just linking to a different static library won't always work anymore due to link-time code generation, but it can be done with some care with compiler options.`)

Comment: @EmployedRussian Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: @Joshua it is something completely different than the volatile. Passing the address shows that side effects might be involved. To reproduce the volatile behaviour you have to call this function before every access and after every modification. It does not make too much sense. Try to replicate the behavior from example 2 and 3 in my answer.

Comment: You should make it clear, however: `volatile` is ONLY to be used with signal handlers or with special hardware that uses memory-mapped I/O.

Comment: Could you clarify in your answer what IPC is an acronym for?

Comment: The Standard explicitly provides that the semantics of `volatile` accesses are Implementation Defined.  This provision would be meaningless if an implementation's specified treatment of `volatile` could not be regarded as defining the behavior of actions that would be data races *in the absence of such specification*.  MSVC and all compilers I've looked at other than those based on clang and gcc either have an option to process a volatile write as a memory clobber, or do so by default.  C would have been useless for many tasks without a way of forcing compilers to assume a memory clobber...

Comment: ...but the fact that compilers intended for tasks which might require such a thing would treat `volatile` in such fashion meant there was no need for the Standard to provide any other means.

Comment: Not to cause too much controversy, but when you take a lock accessing a protected variable, you only need one barrier (hence the function taking address) until you release the lock again.

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE: This answer refers to [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70490645/3) of the question. Meanwhile, the question has been changed, so that this answer no longer directly corresponds to the question.**

According to [§5.1.2.4 ¶25 and ¶4 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4p25), two different threads accessing the same memory location using non-atomic operations in an unordered fashion causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), if at least one thread is writing to that memory location.

Therefore, it is legal for a compiler to assume that no other thread will change a non-atomic non-volatile variable, unless the threads are synchronized in some way.

If thread synchronization is used (for example a mutex), then the compiler is no longer allowed to assume that a variable has not been modified by another thread, unless a [memory order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order) was used that allows the compiler to continue to make this assumption.

In your question, you state that you are attempting to order threads using "signals". However, in ISO C, "signals" cannot be used for thread synchronization. According to [§7.14.1.1 ¶7 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1p7), using the function `signal` in a multithreaded program results in undefined behavior.

If you instead mean signalling a condition variable using the function [`cnd_signal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/cnd_signal), then yes, condition variables (which also use mutexes) can be used for proper thread synchronization.

If you are instead referring to platform-specific functionality, then I cannot comment on that, as you did not specify any specific platform in your question.

Comment: That only applies to data race conditions when "neither happens before the other". What if the value is read clearly after a modification from another thread?

Comment: @xiver77 What makes you think it is "clearly after"? Only atomics and mutexes can make that so.

Comment: `a non-atomic variable, unless the threads are synchronized.` definitely wrong

Comment: @o11c Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: @0__: As far as I can tell, my sentence that you quoted is correct. Would you please elaborate on what you consider wrong in that sentence?

Comment: non volatile variable. Non atomic access is UB in those circumstances, but there another concept of side effect prone

Comment: An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the
implementation or have other unknown side effects. Therefore any expression referring
to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine

Comment: @0__: Yes, you are right. Although OP was not talking about volatile variables, I guess you are right that I should specify that my statements only apply to non-volatile variables. I have therefore added the word "non-volatile" to my answer.

Comment: I'm using `sigwait` to communicate between threads. Mutexes aren't necessary in my specific application.

Answer (score 1):

> That only applies to data race conditions when "neither happens before the other". What if the value is read clearly after a modification from another thread?

"Happens before" is somewhat of a tricky concept. If the language standard says, "A happens before B," it does not mean that A always is guaranteed to happen before B in real time. Its meaning only becomes clear when we understand it as a [*transitive relationship*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation): If, according to the standard, A "happens before" B, and B "happens before" C; then we can infer that A "happens before" C.

But, does A *actually* happen before C *in real-time?*

Let's imagine two threads. One of them updates a shared variable that is protected by a mutex:

```c
void writer(...) {
    mytype_t new_value = create_new_value(...);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    global_var = new_value;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

The other thread accesses the same variable:

```c
void reader(...) {
    mytype_t local_copy;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    local_copy = global_var;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    do_something_with(local_copy);
```

One "happens before" rule, alluded to in a comment by user17732522, is that within any single thread, everything "happens" in *program order.* That is to say, because `global_var = new_value;` appears in the source code of the `writer(...)` function before `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);` then the assignment must "happen before" the unlock within any one call to `writer(...)`.

Another rule says that unlocking a mutex in one thread "happens before" some other thread locks the same mutex.

From these rules, we can infer that ***IF*** some thread A calls `writer(...)` and locks the mutex before some other thread B enters `reader(...)`, then when thread B eventually acquires the mutex and reads the `global_var`, it will read the value that thread A wrote.

But that's a big "***IF*!**" Nothing that I have shown in this example actually guarantees that thread A actually *will* call `writer()` before thread B calls `reader()`. You would have to add some higher-level inter-thread communication if you wanted to ensure that the threads actually did call those functions in any particular real-time order.